# pymodus unknown message

Tags: python, serial, sensor

I am using Pymodbus in Raspberry Pi for data acquisition from Modbus rtu (RS485) sensors. Other sensors worked perfectly fine so coding is ok.

However one particular sensors is giving me this message instead of the data value.

```
ReadHoldingRegistorResponse (1).
```

can someone tell me what does this signify.